# Downsampling for more than 2 classes

Tags: python, pandas, downsampling

I am creating a simple code which allows to down-sample a dataframe when your target variable has more than 2 classes.

Let `df` be our arbitrary dataset and `'TARGET_VAR'` a categorical variable with more than 2 classes.

```
import pandas as pd
label='TARGET_VAR' #define the target variable

num_class=df[label].value_counts() #creates list with the count of each class value
temp=pd.DataFrame() #create empty dataframe to be filled up

for cl in num_class.index: #loop through classes
    #iteratively downsample every class according to the smallest
    #class 'min(num_class)' and append it to the dataframe.
    temp=temp.append(df[df[label]==cl].sample(min(num_class)))

df=temp #redefine initial dataframe as the subsample one

del temp, num_class #delete temporary dataframe
```

Now I was wondering, is there a way to do this in a more refined way? e.g. without having to create the temporary dataset?
I tried to figure out a way to "vectorize" the operation for multiple classes but didn't get anywhere. Below is my idea, which can easily be implemented for 2 classes but I have no idea how to expand it to the multiple classes case.

This works perfectly if you have 2 classes

```
 df= pd.concat([df[df[label]==num_class.idxmin()],\
 df[df[label]!=num_class.idxmin()].sample(min(num_class))])
```

This allows you to pick the right amount of observations for the other classes but the classes will not necessarily be equally represented.

```
 df1= pd.concat([df[df[label]==num_class.idxmin()],\
 df[df[label]!=num_class.idxmin()].sample(min(num_class)*(len(num_class)-1))])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something similar to this:

```
label='TARGET_VAR'

g = df.groupby(label, group_keys=False)
balanced_df = pd.DataFrame(g.apply(lambda x: x.sample(g.size().min()))).reset_index(drop=True)
```

I believe this will produce the result you want, feel free to ask any further questions.

### Edit

Fixed the code according to OP's suggestion.

Comment: Hi Gustavo, thanks for your answer! I didn't know the groupby method. It's really powerful! However this way I am still creating a temporary object any idea of its properties? Do you know if it could become problematic (mainly in terms of memory) if the original dataframe `df` gets very big?

Comment: I believe it will perform similar to your previous approach, just cleaner. But feel free to mock a big dataframe and benchmark both methods. Pick the one that suits you better.

Answer (score 1):

This code is used for `oversampling` instances of the minority class or `undersampling` instances of the majority class. It should be used only on the training set. Note: `activity` is the label

```
balanced_df=Pdf_train.groupby('activity',as_index = False,group_keys=False).apply(lambda s: s.sample(100,replace=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

Gustavo's answer is correct but has a small problem (and for some reason I can't edit his answer).

```
label='TARGET_VAR'

g = df.groupby(label, group_keys=False)
balanced_df = pd.DataFrame(g.apply(lambda x: 
x.sample(g.size().min()).
reset_index(drop=True)))
```

Here the index will be reset for each group and the final dataframe will have repeating row indices. If we define the number of elements in the minority class as `n`:

```
idx, data 
0,   ...
1,   ...
.,   ...
.,   ...
.,   ...
n,   ...
0,   ...
1,   ...
.,   ...
.,   ...
.,   ...
n,   ...
```

The following tweak will solve the issue

```
g = df.groupby(label, group_keys=False)
balanced_df = pd.DataFrame(g.apply(lambda x: 
x.sample(g.size().min()))).reset_index(drop=True)
```

If we now define the total number of elements of the `balanced_df` as `N=n*k`, with `k` being the number of different classes. The index will look like this:

```
idx, data 
0,   ...
1,   ...
.,   ...
.,   ...
.,   ...
N,   ...
```